# Can I get info about device in react native?

Tags: react-native

How I should get the info about device in react native:

— What applications I have used and how many hours?

— The percentage of battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to your question, yes, you can get info about your device in React Native.

For a basic usage you should check libraries already built like [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info)

And to access information from "outside" the scope of your app, you'll need to implemente your own solution. [React Native - Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios)

Hope this helps! :)